# Sharing ivy configurations

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I'm maintaining multiple projects backed by ivy configurations. Many configurations overlap, such as:

- common build configurations ( pmd, findbugs );
- dependency groups ( spring );

Is there a way to import these dependencies by referencing a shared configuration?

---

*N.B.* Please don't suggest Maven, as I know about it, but it is not (yet) an option for these particular projects.

Answer (score 2):

Does [include](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0-rc1/ivyfile/include.html) do what you need, or is the problem more complicated?

From the documentation:

```
<ivy-module version="1.0">
  <info organisation="myorg"
         module="mymodule"/>
  <configurations>
    <include file="path/to/included-configurations.xml"/>
    <conf name="conf3"/>
  </configurations>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency name="mymodule1" rev="1.0"/>
    <dependency name="mymodule2" rev="2.0" conf="conf2,conf3->*"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

with included-configurations.xml like this:

```
<configurations defaultconfmapping="*->@">
  <conf name="conf1" visibility="public"/>
  <conf name="conf2" visibility="private"/>
</configurations>
```

Update: For dependencies, I'm not sure it is possible. I found [a discussion](http://marc.info/?l=ivy-dev&m=117457763528651&w=2) on importing dependencies that indicates this is by design to avoid circular dependencies.

Perhaps you could write a script to process a referenced ivy file and inline the dependencies into your project?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like to have the dependencies included as well, for instance import a 'findbugs' configuration and them all the dependencies are pulled in.

Comment: Sorry my Ivy powers are weak. I've added an update showing what I've found on dependency processing.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I would solve the problem by using `svn:externals` (if you're using Subversion) and not Ivy.

You place all your common configurations into a *config* Subversion project and simply use `svn:externals` to import it into other projects.

As example, you can take a look at my [config project](http://code.google.com/p/workingonit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/config) on Google Code: